# Is this working properly - Sum of Fibonacci in Python 3

Tags: python, numbers, sum, fibonacci

I have a task to make a program that will sum the first 100 Fibonacci numbers. I checked my output in Python, and my output in QBasic 64 and they aren't same. I checked with different inputs also.

```
Input: 10
Output: 89
-----------
Input: 100
Output: 573147844013817084101
```

Is it correct ?

Here is my code:

```
n = int(input())
print()

p = 0
d = 1
z = p + d

print(str(p) + ' + ' + str(d) + ' = ' + str(z))

for i in range(n - 2):

    p = d
    d = z
    z = p + d
    print(str(p) + ' + ' + str(d) + ' = ' + str(z))

print('Sum:', z)
```

EDIT: Code edited again, check it now. I just found on Wikipedia.. It depends from what number you start the loop. So if I use (0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, and 34) as first 10 Fibonacci numbers, the sum is going to be 88, not 89.

Comment: Your QBasic implementation probably overflowed.

Comment: I guess you are going a bit further as you have already calculated the first 2 prime numbers as 0 and 1 So I guess you need to run the `for` loop upto `n-3` times I think.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The sums of the first ten and 100 fibonacchi number would be 88 and 573147844013817084100, respectively:

```
>>> cache = {}

>>> def fib(n):
        if n == 0: return 0
        if n == 1: return 1
        if not n in cache:
            cache[n] = fib(n - 1) + fib(n - 2)
        return cache[n]

>>> sum([fib(i) for i in range(10)])
88
>>> sum([fib(i) for i in range(100)])
573147844013817084100
```

Comment: But the question is about sum of the Fibonacci sequence.

Answer (score 0):

In your loop you are already starting the iteration at the 3rd position, since you set. So set your range to (n -2).

0:  1
1 : 1
2 : 1
3 : 2
4 : 3
5 : 5

Answer (score 0):

To get the ***sum*** of the Fibonacci numbers, using **zero** as the first in the series, you need to do this:

```
def run_it(n):
    N2 = 0
    N1 = 0
    N = 0
    z = N
    for i in range(n):
        print(N,z)
        N2 = N1
        N1 = N
        if N is 0: N = 1
        else: N = N1 + N2
        z = z + N

run_it(int(input('Number: ')))
```

To calculate the sum using **one** as the start of the series, change the initial value of N from zero to one.